# Unable to run .apk on some off Genymotion devices

Tags: android, genymotion

I simulate Samsung Galaxy S7 (API 23) using Genymotion, and then install arm-translation and after restarting device I install my application by drag and drop. 
but I get following error:

```
Unfortunately, <application name> has stopped.
```

Here is terminal log:

```
Failed to connect to VM (TcpStream) for main host connection, IP:Port=192.168.56.101:25000!!!
OpenGPL connected to 192.168.56.101:25000
port 22468 will be used for OpenGL data connections
```

and here is log file from when I run device and application:

```
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] Proxy configuration: no proxy used
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] Host date and time: "12 Mar 2017 13:14:24 -0400"
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] Proxy configuration: no proxy used
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] GET  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/content/video" ) 
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] "Local socket created at path : /tmp/0054dd293a15aa9e4d99002d5631b4ca"
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [warning] ****  STARTING VIRTUAL DEVICE  ****
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [warning] Player version: "2.8.1"
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Loading "vboxmanage" plugin
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Plugin "vboxmanage" loaded
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Chipset: "GenuineIntel"
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] CPUID 0x1 (Intel): ECX= "c00e3bd"
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Path: "VBoxManage"
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("list", "hostinfo")
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] [System properties] Online physical CPU number: 2
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] [System properties] Online virtual CPU number: 2
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] [System properties] Max CPU number: 4
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] [System properties] Max memory size: 3953
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] get "vboxnet0" from host.only.interface
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] [findHostOnlyInterface] Looking for compatible host-only interface
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("list", "hostonlyifs")
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [warning] [VBox] [getSavedHostOnlyInterface] Checking "vboxnet0" interface status (  QHostAddress( "192.168.56.1" )  )
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] [getSavedHostOnlyInterface] "vboxnet0" Interface seems compatible
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("list", "dhcpservers")
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] [checkIfInterfaceHasValidDhcp] "HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet0" DHCP server is associated with "vboxnet0" interface
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] [checkIfInterfaceHasValidDhcp] "vboxnet0" interface is compatible
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("--version")
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] VM engine version: "4.3.36_Ubuntur105129"
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "S7_API23")
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "enumerate", "S7_API23")
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
Mar 12 13:14:24 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "S7_API23")
Mar 12 13:14:25 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
Mar 12 13:14:25 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "S7_API23")
Mar 12 13:14:25 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
```

but the application run successfully on HTC ONE (API 17). what's the problem and how can I fix it?
The .apk is from play store so the apk file is ok.

Comment: Genymotion doesn't need any extra arm-translation package. Try with a clean device. If your app crashes, there has to be a stack trace. Do you use Crashlytics? Does a debug version crash as well? This can be caused by changes in API 23, not the emulator itself. For example apps on API 23 can crash if you don't check for permissions at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I use that package since i get following error while installing: An error occured while deploying the file.
This probably means that the app contains ARM native code 
and your Genymotion device cannot run ARM instructions. 
You should either build your native code to x86 or install an ARM 
translation tool in your device.

Comment: no need for genymotion just use default emulator with intel HAXAM

Comment: I need to run it on Genymotion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem occurred by `arm-translation`. I find the `x86` version of the application apk and could install it on all Genymotion devices with out need to flash using `arm-translation`.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this error occurred during windows run android-studio and Genymotion if your pc/laptop is week in cpu and ram and
i used Genymotion 2 weeks Ago and this error happened a lot of time .

for fix this bloody error do Following steps

1- try Enable **hardware virtualization** in bios

2-Try re-install your app it may help or try clean data.

3-update your vBox(Virtual Box) to latest version.

4- try to Update Your Genymotion to latest Version.

5-some time when you use another emulator like Bluestacks this error occurred try to uninstall Bluestakcs and use One emulator or change port of your Emulator.

if none of them work try use another Emulator like nox , andy and etc

hope it help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. hardware virtualization is enabled. and all Genymotion devices run correctly. I have tried uninstalling and installing the app but it didn't work, also my Virtual Box and Genymotion are the latest version. Since I want to check the app in different API, I choose Genymotion as an Emulator.